# Tests for normal distribution

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Given some data, is there any test to determine if the data fits a normal distribution ( the mean and variance are not mentioned )

Comment: You could make a histogram of the data, draw a QQ plot, use goodness of fit ... there are many tests for normality. Usually, if you want a rough idea of whether or not you're sampling from a normal population, you make a histogram of the data and test for outliers. If the histogram is approximately bell shaped, doesn't look multimodal, isn't too sharply skewed, and you don't observe too many outliers, then you're in good shape to assume normality.

Answer (score 1):

The Shapiro-Wilk test is a formal test of normality-in-general for a random sampled data - without reference to specific numerical values of the mean $\mu$ or variance $\sigma^2.$

For example, vector `x` has observations from a nomral
population and vector `y` has observations from an exponential population.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rnorm(100, 1, 1)
summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -2.039   0.438   1.120   1.109   1.739   4.202 
shapiro.test(x)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x
W = 0.98906, p-value = 0.5895
```

The null hypothesis that the population is normal is not rejected at the 5% level: P-value = $0.59 > 0.05 = 5\%.$

```
y = rexp(100, 1)
summary(y)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.008152 0.329992 0.810329 1.175030 1.679118 4.713232 
shapiro.test(y)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  y
 W = 0.85789, p-value = 2.346e-08
```

The null hypothesis that the population is normal is rejected at the 5% level: P-value $\approx 0 < 0.05 = 5\%.$

Also, as suggested in the Comment by @MatthewPilling one can look at a normal probability plot (Q-Q plot), in which normal data should roughly follow a straight line. (One should not be too fussy about fit to a straight line for the lower and highest values in the sample.

Here are Q-Q plots of vectors `x` (left panel) and `y`.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 qqnorm(x); qqline(x, col="darkgreen")
 qqnorm(y); qqline(y, col="darkgreen")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

With samples as large as $n = 100$ is is usually
possible to distinguish samples from normal populations for samples from non-normal populations. But for smaller
samples, the distinction may not be so clear.

Here is a repetition of the above, but with samples of
size $n = 15.$

```
set.seed(1213)
x = rnorm(15, 1, 1)
shapiro.test(x)$p.val
[1] 0.02057266
y = rexp(15, 1)
shapiro.test(y)$p.val
[1] 0.002650913
```

The Shapiro-Wilk test mistakenly rejects normality of `x` at the
5% level (moderately close call), correctly rejects
normality of `y` with a very small P-value.

Normal probability plots: We might be willing to excuse
the ragged plot at left for `x` as "perhaps roughly linear", but the plot at right 'y' is clearly not linear.

[image]

Boxplots show some left-skewness for `x` (at left), but three high high outliers out of $n=15$ for `y`.

For samples as small
as $n = 15,$ one can often only speculated about normality.

```
boxplot(x, y, col="skyblue2", pch=19, names=T)
```

[image]